# Android studio update failed

Tags: android-studio

I have problem for update android studio from 0.8.9 to 0.8.14. Please help me. How fix it ?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can can only update to this version incrementally from 0.8.12 or 0.8.13; for all other versions you will need to install it from scratch

http://tools.android.com/download/studio/canary/0-8-14